# How does SharePoint 2013 compile suggested interests for user profiles?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

When editing your profile for SharePoint 2010 or 2013, certain multi-line fields such as "Job Skills" or "Interests" offer potential values as you type. Originally I thought these suggestions were coming from other profiles - examples of what other people had used in those fields. After some research, though, that doesn't seem to be case. For instance, on my own profile, I get the following when I enter the letter "p":

[image]

I'd like to find out where the [keywords] items are coming from, especially, but I also need to correct the circled duplicate (Production vs. Productions). I couldn't find any profiles using the job title "Productions Manager", or for that matter "President", and I'm assuming that "Prodution" as a department is a typo somewhere. I'm hoping that these are static values stored somewhere where I can access and modify them, but I haven't been able to find much on it so far.

**How does SharePoint compile this list of suggestions, and where are they stored specifically?**

*Note - if it's a list somewhere in the config database, I'd be curious which table as well... purely for academic purposes, of course.*

Answer (score 2):

They are values stored in the Managed Metadata Service Application, specifically in the People Term group. In your sample above Project Management is in the Keywords term set. "Production Manager" and "Productions Manager" is in the Job Title term set. These term sets are populated from the User Profile Import process. So the typos are in your active directory (or were ever the import is pulling the Job Title, Department and Location data). In most organizations this is AD.

The proper way to "fix" this is to clean up AD first. Then run an import, this will clean up the profiles. Then you can remove the terms. If you edit or remove the terms without fixing AD they will just get recreated.

Oh, even academically, don't mess with your SharePoint databases. It is not supported.